# PHP MySQL multiple search word using array for word to word translation

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Pretty new to php and currently making a multiple array search word to word translator using MySQL database as source of the translation. Im using 1 table that has 2 column. The first column is language 1, and the second column is language 2. Language 2 is the translation of language 1. The process is i want to search multiple translation form language 1 and shows tho output of translation 2. Lets say for example user input "word3 word2 word5 word4 word1" from language 1 and the output of language 2 should be the same order by input like "translation3 translation2 translation5 translation4 translation1". But after splitting the string to array the problem by using OR in my sql query makes the result display in database order. If im not using OR the result will not be displayed. So the problem i want to solve is:

1. Shows the result of translation in order to what user input
2. Using the exact input word by user to find the translation
3. Show the result of translation with the repeated input word like word1 word1 word1 = translation1 translation1 translation1 if possible.

Please help if you have any solution as i cant seem to find any solution on the internet. Thanks. This is my code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['transl']))
{
$keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['input_text']);
$keys = explode(" ",$keyword);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM language WHERE language_1 = '".$keyword."' " ;


foreach($keys as $k){

    $sql .= " OR language_1 = '".$k."' ";


}
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if($result){

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

        echo $row['language_2'];
    }
}

echo $sql;
} 
?>
```

Comment: Translating text isn't as straight forward as that. Grammar is different and some languages add words before prior to words, like `the`. Some languages change the word order so that it's word1 word3 word2.

Comment: this translator does not require grammar, its just a direct translator

Comment: @Bezman Did my post helped you? do you have other constrains?

Answer (score 0):

You can load the words from your SQL with the `OR` query as you did and save as associative array - but when translate it I recommend you use 2 arrays with `language_1` and `language_2` and then use [str-replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to swap the words.

Consider the following:

```
$dic = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $dic[$row['language_1']] = $row['language_2']; 
}
```

Now you can take the keys (language_1) and the values (language_2) and use as:

```
$newSentence = str_replace(array_keys($dic), array_values($dic), $input);
```